# Why am I sometimes getting exception "pdb not loaded" and how can i solve it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the screenshot it's something with the speech.pdb
But in other cases sometimes it's something else pdb

In this cases i played with the checkbox of the Enable Voices i clicked on it few times and then after 3-4 times checked unchecked it i got the exception.

I can't make it to happen on other situations but i had the exception this window also on another case without pdb.

[image: Exception]

Comment: Not all symbols are available from Microsoft, and you should ignore such.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the project dependencies for the solution and ensuring that the project with the post-build event is dependent on the project that wasn't loading, and the pdb will load during debug.
When you right click on your Solution in Visual Studio there's a Project Dependencies option and on the window that opens there's a Build order tab where you can set the order the projects are built in.